# Why am I getting CORS origin although I defined cors "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and set it with the value " * "

Tags: node.js, cors

I am creating a MEAN app. I have deployed the frontend on netlify and the backend on heroku.

Locally, all the routes works without any error.

But on production mode I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mybackendLink.herokuapp.com/api/upload-image-pub/614f30ce01777500042b0238' from origin 'https://myfrontendlink.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In my app.js file, I have this CORS configuration:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

    next();
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to avoid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Error,

```
const cors = requires('cors');
// ..... Other Code
app.use(cors());
```

By usig the cors in your application ads a middlleware you can over come the issue of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`